# Adding a base and a salt to a hydrated complex

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, solubility, coordination-compounds, stability

The question goes like this:

> $\ce{Fe(NO3)3}$ V= $\pu{1 liter}$ and $\ce{[Fe(NO3)3]} =\pu{0.1 moles/liter}$.
>
> Calculate the $\mathrm{pH}$ of this solution using the values of $K$ given.
>
> We add a solid of $\pu{0.2 moles}$ of $\ce{NaOH}$. Give the reactions and the $\mathrm{pH}$. How many precipitation is formed?
>
> After this we add $\pu{0.5 moles}$ of $\ce{KCN}$. Give the reactions, the $\mathrm{pH}$ and the end concentrations in equilibrium.
>
> Given:
>
> - $K_\mathrm{st}\,\ce{[Fe(CN)6]^{3-}} = 1\times10^{42}$
> - $K_\mathrm{a}\, \ce{HCN} = 4\times10^{-10}$
> - $K_\mathrm{a_1}\,\ce{Fe^{3+}} = 6.3\times10^{-3}$
> - $K_\mathrm{s}\,\ce{Fe(OH)3} = 1\times10^{-38}$

Up to and including the addition of $\ce{NaOH}$ I understand what is expected and how I should solve for this. However, as soon as the $\ce{KCN}$ is added, I don't know if I should let the $\ce{Fe^3+}$ react first with the $\ce{CN-}$, with the $\ce{OH-}$, or if I should establish a new equilibrium starting from the previous one?

My first thought would be to let the cyanide react completely with the iron-ion, and only form the iron hydroxide with the remaining ions [because $K_\mathrm{st}\,\ce{[Fe(CN)6]^{3-}} >> K_\mathrm{s} \ce{Fe(OH)3}$]. However, in some provided solutions of similar exercises, they seem to let the hydroxide react first with acid, not caring about a higher solubility constant.

Comment: $\ce{Fe_3(NO_3)_3}$ does not exist ! Only $\ce{Fe(NO_3)_3}$ does exist !

Comment: What is the meaning of $\ce{K_{st}}$ ?

Comment: @Maurice $\ce{K_{st}}$ = $\ce{K_{form}}$ = $\ce{1/K_{diss}}$, it's the product of all the stability constants inbetween $\ce{Fe3+}$ ... $\ce{Fe3(CN)3}$ ... $\ce{Fe3(CN)6^{3-}}$

Comment: Well ! $\ce{Fe_3(CN)_3}$ and $\ce{Fe_3(CN)_6^{3-}}$ do not exist

Comment: If you know how to solve this, you should be able to figure out. After you add the $\ce{NaOH}$, the pH will be still acidic, and some $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ will precipitate. If you disregard this amount (assuming it wont be solving back), then after adding the $\ce{KCN}$ you will end up with a basic solution, for which you need to solve a system of equations to get the right answer. You don't need to worry about which will react first, since they will create and equilibrium.

Comment: Whats the definition of $\ce{K_{a1}Fe^{3+}}$? Obviously it is not about hydroxides, then what is is about? The first proton dissociation from the coordination sphere of the hexaaqua complex? You also mentioned a hydrate complex in the title but you did not mention any water complexes in the post, nor any constant for it.

Comment: @AndrewKovács The $K_\mathrm{a_1}\,\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ goes for the following reaction $$\ce{Fe(H2O)6^{3+} + H2O <=> Fe(H2O)5(OH)^{2+} + H3O+}$$There are no other constants given, which I think suggests the next acidic reaction of the iron complex is negligible.